# how to store the ping statistics after giving ctrl+c in a text file

Tags: ping

```
mininet> h1 ping h2
PING 10.0.0.2 (10.0.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=15.2 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=5.43 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=0.243 ms
^C64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_req=13 ttl=64 time=0.216 ms

--- 10.0.0.2 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 12016ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.136/1.809/15.257/4.119 ms
mininet>
```

I want to capture number of packets transmitted,packets received,packet loss percentage into a text file.
how to do this?
please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just you have to type : `ping ip >>out.txt`

This will help you.

Comment: Yeah I tried this way..,only the lines before giving ctrl+c are captured but I want ping statistics displayed after giving ctrl+c.@Cast_A_Way

Comment: try this and let me know :

`ping -c 5 -q 127.0.0.1 >> out.txt`

Comment: Yeah it is working..but how to give this command through python scripting-@Cast_A_Way

Comment: Please accept the answer if you are satisfied.
For your python query, add this python code :

`import subprocess`
subprocess.Popen("ping -c 5 -q 127.0.0.1 >> out.txt")`

Comment: Correct above comment  like this ::

`import subprocess`
`subprocess.Popen("ping -c 5 -q 127.0.0.1 >> out.txt")`

Comment: I tried to give above ping command through subprocess.Popen() as you mentioned.,but Iam getting the error OSError[Error2]:No such file or directory -@Cast_A_Way